# L'adjectif « gender-affirming » se traduit-il par « d'affirmation de genre » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, adjectifs, terminologie, santé-et-médecine

Je m'intéresse surtout à l'adjectif dans « gender-affirming (chest reconstruction surgery) » ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/gender-affirming) : ayant trait à un processus... ; [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affirm) : soutenir ou encourager...). Je l'ai trouvé dans une [fiche](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26545116) du GDT sur le *traitement hormonal de réassignation sexuelle/de sexe*. Sur [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=GENDER%20AFFIRMATION%20CHEST%20SURGERY&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) on trouve « chirurgie d'[affirmation](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/affirmation) de [genre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/genre) au haut du corps ».

Les termes *affirmation* et plus particulièrement *affirmation de genre* traduisent-ils [universellement](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18940648) ce qui est exprimé en langue anglaise et autrement comment l'exprimerait-on (par exemple, va-t-on préciser *réassignation* avec un complément et si oui, comment ; en portant une attention particulière au choix de prépositions etc.) ?

Comment: La fiche du GTD est parfaitement audible et correspond à la pratique effectuée, sinon on aurait parlé d'implants, celle du Termium est du franglais : *affirmation de genre* ne correspond pas au *transgenre* usuel. « Chirurgie/Traitement mammaire transgenre » vs « gender-affirming (chest reconstruction surgery) » semble connoté pour les hommes, quid pour une femme que l'on opère pour la masculiniser (et non pour augmenter sa poitrine → Chirurgie mammaire, s'il y a une affirmation de l'ego il n'y a pas d'affirmation de genre induite) ?

Comment: @Personne Quid, bien c'était justement le [cas](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/nova-scotia/elliot-page-transgender-oprah-interview-1.6008582). Peut-être associe-t-on _augmentation_ à _affirmation_, je ne sais pas. Disons qu'incidemment je me demande si une locution avec un nom comme _soutien_ est utile. Il y a aussi la question de savoir si _genre_ est bien compris en français dans ce contexte à l'extérieur du Québec etc. Quand j'ai lu en anglais je me suis demandé comment traduire et le fait qu'on ait équivalence dans le tour comparativement à l'anglais me laisse songeur.

Comment: Elles et ils ont subi une chirurgie ou un traitement mammaire transgenre pour *affirmer leur transformation/choix sexuel*. Pour "affirmer leur nouveau genre" sonne mal  et ne peut être employé que dans un contexte où le mot *transgenre* a été employé.

Comment: @Personne Merci de l'échange, bien c'est ça qui m'intéresse, comment se greffe le terme pour ainsi dire, au processus. Dans ce que j'ai lu c'était clairement la poitrine, mais certainement pas une augmentation, ni le contraire exactement. Pour être plus direct je demanderais, est-ce là une chirurgie qui affirme, ou qui vient _en soutien à_ la réassignation. Mais il se peut que l'élément affirmation soit utile culturellement vu que ce serait à contre-courant. Il y a aussi la question du lexique qui est employé dans une communauté sans être courant nécessairement. Il y a bien des ramifications.

Comment: Ce n'est en tout cas pas une ***chirurgie réparatrice/reconstructrice/correctrice*** des corps en souffrance réelle, atteint de maladies sévères ou avec un handicap avéré, elle n'est pas là pour suppléer les problèmes psychiques qui sont réglés par une ***chirurgie esthétique***.  Les énergies Yin & Yang sont également réparties quel que soit le sexe (pardon pour les prudes, le genre) c'est le regard du conseil de famille et de la société qui pose problème aux mineur·es quand les apparences sont ambigües …

Comment: … et ensuite, c'est d'imposer à la vue des autres ses problèmes (en oubliant, « pour vivre bien vivons cachés » :-) et la solution à leurs problèmes, ou de prouver quelque chose … et ce n'est pas au chirurgien de dire « j'affirme/je soutiens » lui qui ne fait qu'accompagner la psyché en souffrance (bientôt il sera remplacé par un robot). Ces mots sont du jargon de sectes prosélytes (groupes identifiés par des croyances, politiques, activités, revendications …)

Comment: Personne a eu un 5 mai chargé, je vois...